# Flexbox code working on all browsers except Safari, is their an alternative or patch?

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I need to display in correct order per every 3 columns, with auto width enabled for every extra html list elements.

This is my example:

```
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

I want to convert the output like this:

```
1 4 7 10
2 5 8 11
3 6 9 12
```

This is what I have tried so far and works absolutely fine on every other browser but not compatible with Safari browser.

```
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  -ms-flex-direction: column;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 150px;
  width: auto;
}

li {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
```

is their an alternative way to produce my output ? for just safari browser, or is their an alternatives way with css, js / jquery or perhapes some php filters looping html to a list variable / array

The closest example on patching this with jquery is mimicking flex-wrap:wrap with this code:

```
<style>
#wrap{float:left; width:50px; height:150px; clear: both;}
</style>
<script>
$("ul > :lt(3)").wrapAll( "<ul id='wrape'></ul>" ); 
</script>
```

however I cant seem to find a way to keep repeating this per every 3 list.

its important I get this working for Safari browser so far I cant seem to solve this problem at all, I would appropriate any help :)

Test link:
http://jsfiddle.net/rafcastro77/3zd7yspg/59/

i finally managed to patch it here is my example of it working:

```
   <style>
.new{float:left; width:50px; border:1px solid #000; color:green; }
</style>
<script>
   var divs = $("ul > li");
    for(var i = 0; i < divs.length; i+=3) {
      divs.slice(i, i+3).wrapAll("<div class='new'></div>");
    }
</script>
```

a working version with output:
http://jsfiddle.net/rafcastro77/3zd7yspg/66/

i hope this helps many others if they are looking for an alternative way instead of flexbox

Comment: What does Safari do different? ... and which Safari version are we talking about?

Comment: Does this work? .. `flex-flow: column wrap;` ... instead of `flex-direction/flex-wrap`

Comment: I can't test now in safari, but width:25%; margin: 0 auto; for li element

Comment: im using safari 5.1.7, i know the latests safari version might support it but i need it working on most browsers possible. i tried flex-flow: column wrap; that does not work.

Comment: width:25% on lists its not good enough i need it to work even if the was more elements to be added, needs to be flexible

Comment: Do you mean Safari for Windows 5.1.7 ? ... if so, you can drop that, they stopped updating it almost 2 years ago ... If you support 2 versions back on today's latest browser in general, you will likely catch +95% of the market, and if customer ask for older, charge them extra.

Comment: Check this table and you'll get a good summary of which browser to bother to support: http://caniuse.com/usage-table ... browser versions more than 2 versions back and with percent less than 0.5 you can just drop

Comment: thanks for your help :)

Comment: I got your comment in my other answer. I'm glad you found a solution. By the way, you are allowed to answer your own questions. So instead of posting your answer as an edit to the question, consider posting an actual answer. You are also permitted to accept your own answer (but not upvote it).

Comment: Thanks for the help ! really appreciate and I will do :)